# Addition of unequal sized Tensors in theano

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, deep-learning

I am new to theano and was looking at this tutorial : http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html . I have pasted the line in question. The pooled_out(output after convolution and maxout) is a 4D Tensor of size (a,b,c,d) whereas ***b***(bias) is a vector. Even after dimshuffle dimension for ***b*** is (1,b,1,1). How can we add two unequal sized Tensors. Or does theano automatically copies the same value for ***b*** at all other places  for same value of second dimension of tensor ***b*** ? The comment on top of it says "Each bias will thus be broadcasted across mini-batches and feature map width & height" is that what it means ?

```
self.output = T.tanh(pooled_out + self.b.dimshuffle('x', 0, 'x', 'x'))
```

Answer (score 0):

"Or does theano automatically copies the same value for b at all other places for same value of second dimension of tensor b ?"

This is exactly what will happen. `'x'` in `dimshuffle` means to match the required by the operation dimension of your tensor, 'copying' the value if needed.

That process is called **broadcasting**.